# Understanding sequence unpacking: Why does using a set throw "SyntaxError: can't assign to literal"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a python beginner. I recently learned that list and tuple allow value assignment.

```
## 1)
a=[1,2,3,4]
[j,c,d,f] = a
print (j)  # prints 1
## 2)
t=(6,7,8,9)
(s1,s2,s3,s4) = t
print (s1)  # prints 6
## 3)
m={11,12,13}
{s,d,c}=m
print(s)     #Gives error
```

I am unable to understand this behavior. Why similar operation with set gives error. Also, similar operation is possible with dictionary as well ?
Kindly help and explain.

Comment: A set does not have any inherent ordering, so it is not appropriate to use with unpacking assignment.

Comment: @coldspeed Perhaps the error message could be improved, but I guess *you* don't have control over it :) `{s, d, c} = m` raises `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal` which may be confusing, since `(s, d, c) = m` and `[s, d, c] = m` work as expected. Perhaps the error should be `TypeError: can't assign to set literal`

Comment: Also: `[j,c,d,f] = a` is not needed - `j,c,d,f = a` is enough - when you put [] or () around , it does nothing for the decomposing - my guess would be that it constructs a list / tuple that is immediatly disposed of because it is not stored... not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you see with lists and tuples is called *iterable unpacking*, and is used to unpack values from any sequence into variables (as long as there are as many variables on the left as there are on the right—unless you're using [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)).

Given

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = (1, 2, 3, 4)
c = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

The following are all valid operations:

```
e, f, g, h = a
# Equivalent to
# (e, f, g, h) = a
# Also equivalent to, but slightly different than
# [e, f, g, h] = a
w, x, y, z = b
p, q, r, s = c
```

The syntax is not supported for sets, however, because they do not have any inherent ordering (at least, not until python3.6). So,

```
{p, q, r, s} = a
```

Is invalid syntax (`SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`) because [python's grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) does not support it.